# Return HTML from jQuery GET request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm attempting to return an HTML form from a GET request triggered by jQuery but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. A customer's server will call to mine which will then return a form. I understand the same domain policy comes into play and there are ways around it such as JSONP, but I can't figure out how to return an entire HTML form.

**right now I'm testing on localhost, so I can just use GET to another page on my server without having to worry about same domain policy, if that helps to simplify things**

Here's my thought process.

```
//form_deliver.php
//this code would go on the customer's server which would then call to mine
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<?php
    echo "look at all of this stuff!";
?>
<script> 
    $.getJSON("/form_deliverer.php?form_request=true",function(data) {
            //alert(data.check); //this was just for testing, 
    });
</script>
```

Here's the page that it sends the GET request to

```
//form_deliverer.php
//this code is on my server which will return a form to the customer
<?
if(isset($_GET['form_request'])){
   // echo json_encode(array("check" => "true")); //just for testing
    //return form here
?>
```

For simplicity, let's say this is the form I want to return is

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="textbox" name="text"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_text"/>
</form>
```

**Edit this is my update according to jackJoe's suggestions**

Code on form_deliver.php

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<?php
    echo "look at all of this stuff";
?>
<script> 
    var form_request = "true";
    $.get("/form_deliverer.php", {var: form_request},
        function(data){
        $("#yourdiv").html(data);
    }, "html");
</script>
<div id = "yourdiv">

</div>
```

This is on form_deliverer.php

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['form_request'])){
    return "
    <form method='post'>
        <input type='textbox' name='text'/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit_text'/>
    </form>
    ";
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you really need the `getJSON`? you could use AJAX (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and specify `html` I think that would work for you.

Comment: @jackJoe, I'm not sure. As I said I really don't know how to approach it. Could you please elaborate a bit as to how I could return HTML?

Comment: If you'll eventually use JSONP, you'll have to make the form markup a string, which should be the value of a property of the json-encoded object the server is responding with.

Comment: @bfavaretto I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you possibly do so to the short form I have shown in my post? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you could use `AJAX` or in your case `GET` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and it allows you to return html.

Example:

```
$.get("yourPHP.php", {var: somethingdynamicpassedviajavascript},
     function(data){
     //get the result
     $("#yourdiv").html(data);
}, "html");
```

The end of this function has the return type (in this case "html"). This example would place the HTML into the div `#yourdiv`

Comment: does this require the HTML to be on the customer's server? I want to return it from mine.

Comment: The HTML is what is rendered from the PHP (form_deliverer.php) [or in my example yourPHP.php], so if that PHP is at your server, that will be the HTML used.

Comment: either I'm completely misunderstanding you (which is more than likely the case), or I have some syntax errors. Could you please take a look at my edit?

Comment: You should serialize the form fields (so they are sent with the get), and your code seems ok. I suggest you explore/study a bit more.

Comment: when I serialize nothing is returned. I appreciate the help. I would try to study up some more, but honestly I don't really know what words or technical terms to search. It's difficult when I can really only describe my question without knowing what to actually call it.

Comment: I got it to work. I changed it up a bit. I'll update the code above in case you're curious

Answer (score 1):

If you'll eventually use JSONP, you'll have to make the form markup a string, which should be the value of a property of the json-encoded object the server is responding with.

So, your server will have to echo something like this:

```
<?php
$o = new stdClass();
$o->formHTML = '<form>...</form>';
echo json_encode($o);
?>
```